# sql when field2 = 'something' then field3 like

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My query is

```
Select 
       NO,
       Timestamp,
       Event_type,
       Comments
From   TableA
Where NO = '12345';
```

but for `Event_type`, I only want to select when `event_type in ('ABC_XYZ','Comment_Change'`) 
 
and `Comments` field must be like `Cause:%` (when `event_type = 'Comment_change'`)

How can I achieve this where condition?

Comment: I am sorry I was missing something please see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select 
       NO,
       Timestamp,
       Event_type,
       Comments
From   TableA
Where event_type = 'ABC_XYZ' or
      (event_type =  'Comment_Change' and Commentsfield like 'Cause:%')
```

Comment: I have one question for you. This is exactly what I was looking for but now I need to do reverse of this. is this possible? I need to find out which `NO` doesn't consist `Cause:%` when event_type = `Comment_change`

Comment: @Mowgli: Try `event_type =  'Comment_Change' and Commentsfield not like 'Cause:%'`

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
       NO,
       Timestamp,
       Event_type,
       Comments
From   TableA
Where NO = '12345'
and event_type = 'Comment_Change' 
And Comments like 'Cause:%';
```

This seems to be what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql:

```
Select
    no,
    Timestamp,
    if(event_type='comment_change',event_type,null) as event_type,
    Concat('Cause: ', comments) as comments
from TableA
where no='12345';
```

Answer (score 1):

with a case construct

```
select case when comments like 'Cause:%'  
and event_type in ('ABC_XYZ','Comment_Change') then event_type 
else 'something else' event_type
from tableA
where no = '12345'
```